# pyramid_mongodb scaffold not activated after install

Tags: pyramid, pymongo, scaffold

I have installed Pyramid 1.3.x and pyramid_mongodb scaffold, but it does not appear when I run `pcreate --list-templates`.

Comment: Even after installed pyramid-1.2.7 it doesn't appear, but when I exec: paster create --list-templates it show an exception: Warning: could not load entry point pyramid_mongodb (ImportError: No module named pyramid_mongodb.paster_templates)

Comment: Pyramid 1.3 is still in alpha. There has been some major changes with scaffolding so don't expect every scaffold to work out of the box.

Comment: I've alsom tryed with pyramid 1.2 and the same.

Comment: Have you tried it in a new fresh virtualenv?

Comment: In case it matters, I wrote that project, http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=pyramid_mongo&version=0.1 Still haven't found time writting scaffolding but soon I'll include some great things. It's as simple to use as config.include('pyramid_mongo'), I'm planning to develop a scaffold that looks pretty much like the zodb one. Documentation here http://packages.python.org/pyramid_mongo/

Answer (score 1):

I gather that stuff is registered to work with pyramid scaffolding by making it a `[pyramid.scaffold]` entry point. In addition, pyramid_mongodb has a dependency on PasteScript (*see **update**).

The issue is that pyramid_mongodb is missing some information in its setup.py. I've [forked the github repo and fixed it](https://github.com/kojiromike/pyramid_mongodb/commit/78b3bd40ddcd0aeb5505e8fa30aa224a855e6a47) so it should work in the future.

**Update**: The dependency on PasteScript is not entirely the best approach, and I'll update it on github soon. The issue of supporting multiple versions of scaffolding is [documented on Pyramid's website](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/scaffolding.html#supporting-older-pyramid-versions)

Answer (score 0):

This was not listed for me either but you should still be able to run `./bin/pip install pyramid_mongodb` to install with those options.

When you run `pserve development.ini`, you may get an error `pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure:`. If you install MongoDB and run the daemon, your Pyramid app should connect.